# Error when creating snaps for ros subscriber/publisher tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to snaps. I am following this tutorial to get started with ros and snaps.

> https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/03/22/distributing-a-ros-system-among-multiple-snaps/

I was successful in creating the ros-base snap that contains roscore and the basic ros packages. When I try creating a snap for ros-app, I get an error

> Unable to find package path:
> "/home/user/snap-apps/ros-app/parts/ros-app/src/src"

The problem I guess is that, it is looking the sub-directory src/src instread of just src/. Do I need to edit the snapcraft.yaml file to change some paths?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260619/error-when-creating-snaps-for-ros-subscriber/publisher-tutorial/) by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2017-04-28**:
Which version of Snapcraft are you using?

**Comment by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) on 2017-05-01**:
Snapcraft version: 2.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works for me, so it's possible you accidentally diverged from the tutorial somewhere along the line (e.g. the Snapcraft project isn't in the root of the workspace, etc.). That tutorial is actually [a demo in the Snapcraft source tree](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/tree/master/demos/shared-ros), I suggest you start with that.

---

Originally posted by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) with karma: 347 on 2017-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) on 2017-05-04**:
I will try again and let you know.